# error: failed to write bytecode. The system cannot find the path specified. (os error 3).Error in compiling substrate node-template

Tags: rust, build, compilation, rust-cargo, substrate

[image: I get this error while using "cargo build --release" for compiling substrate-node-template. Please tell how o solve this.]

I get this error while using "cargo build --release" for compiling substrate-node-template. Please tell how o solve this.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

It may be that your path is too long, https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/issues/134

Comment: this is true. I rename part of my path from "ClionProject" to “p”, which reduce the path length by 11, the compilation went on.